# How to read pixel colours using Python turtle.py

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm preparing exercises for school classes involving Python's `turtle` library.

The students are already drawing terrific pictures, but I want them to be able to *detect* existing pictures and colours in order to modify the behaviour of their program.

For example I would like to provide them with code which draws a maze using turtle, and then they can write the code to navigate the turtle around the maze (don't worry, I'll start simpler).

Is there a way to detect the colour of the pixels already drawn by the turtle?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used turtle... But if you can save output as picture then you can use opencv to detect color . it gives rgb value

Answer (score 1):

Turtle uses Tkinter canvas, which you can get using `turtle.getcanvas()`, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014347/get-pixel-colors-of-tkinter-canvas) you cannot read the colour of a pixel without using a workaround of converting the canvas to a picture (bitmap) and read the bitmap.

You could try to keep an open array to work as the bitmap of your canvas and update it yourself as you draw new elements on the canvas, although that seems impractical unless the maze is simple and 'squary'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array keep all x and y that is used for the maze in an array like stated above.  Then have a size of a box around the turtle defined for detecting purposes.