# How to make line thicker when we draw on an existing line using turtle in Python?

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics

I am making a drawing using Turtle where I draw a line between two points reading from data. If I want to draw another line exactly on top of this line, it shows the same thickness. Is there a way to tell turtle to draw a thicker line everytime it draws on top of an existing line?

Comment: Alternately, is there a way to find out if a certain point is empty or not, in a turtle drawing?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to check whether you are drawing over an already existing line. You might want to write some code that tracks the turtles movement, and then use that to determine line size.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579631/how-to-read-pixel-colours-using-python-turtle-py asks a similar question but I'm not going to mark this a duplicate because it only offers a vague outline of how to do what you requested. However, it seems like there is no way of doing this using the turtle's existing API and you'd have to come up with a custom solution.